# How can I know what message Gnome is currently displaying through an SSH session?

Tags: server, gnome, ssh, remote, camera

I have a computer I can access remotely via SSH and I also have a camera which gives me feedback from the X11 interface. Today I noticed a message like so:

[image]

Now I'm sure the camera is not going to ever be able to read it (the zoom is not that powerful and the camera is too far). So... I'm looking at the way to determine what message this is looking at the currently running processes. I have full SSH access (i.e. I've full `sudo` and remote X11 access). What would you do to see what that window is all about?

Answer (score 1):

You can install a VNC-Server to look at the screen.

Install `x11vnc`.
Run `x11vnc`.
Connect to the Computer using a VNC-Viewer.

You can take a screenshot copy it to your Computer using sftp.

Install `scrot`.
Run `scrot -D :0 <filename>`.
Run `sftp user@ip` (from your Computer), type `get <filename>` to get download the file and type `exit` to exit sftp.

Comment: That would be nice, but only if I could access a VNC... port is blocked at the moment and I'd have to go to the office to unblock.